# Are there any advantages of Dark Room over The Chest?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Given that getting into the Dark Room is mostly a voluntary decision and there's much less items than in The Chest, is there any practical reason why one would choose going into the Dark Room?

Comment: Achievements and item unlocks. And it's only four items less. Which can possibly be guppy items

Comment: Not four, you also lose all the items from the chests.

Comment: Well, you can still find items in red chests when completing a room in Dark Room, iirc.

Comment: Wait? Since when doesn't the dark room give chest with items like in the chest? I haven't played in a while, but the dark room had the same chest room rewards as the chest

Answer (score 1):

Aside from being required to unlock items for characters/get achievements, the item pool of the chest is that of the sacrifice rooms, since all chests are red chests.

By choosing the Dark Room, you could potentially collect 3 Guppy items, become Guppy, and have an OP finish to your run.

Once you've unlocked everything, though, it's mostly a matter of preference. Personally I choose the Dark Room if I'm not overly powerful that particular run, because I'm not very good at the bullethell fight with Blue Baby (or Isaac).